# How do I switch graphics driver without access to a shell?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, nouveau

I just tried to switch to the nouveau driver (from Nvidia proprietary) on my Ubuntu 14.04 machine, and now I can't access anything. When I start the computer I hear the drumroll when I reach the login screen, but all I see is some weird test screen (squares in different colors, changes every few seconds).

ctrl+alt+fx doesn't work, so I have no way to get a tty. I'm currently writing this from a live usb.

Is there some way for me to change the driver if all I have access to is the filesystem (from the live usb)? Or am I totally screwed?

Comment: Disable the GPU in your BIOS if a laptop or remove the card if a PC.   What does that do?

Comment: When I rebooted from the live USB, the computer then booted from my usual drive and it suddenly worked fine. When I rebooted without the live usb connected, it all crashed down again. So basically I was able to get to my normal computer by restarting from the live usb, and when at my normal desktop I could switch back to the Nvidia driver.

Comment: I'm confused...  Is NVidia enabled and it works now?  Or disabled and it works?

Comment: The Nvidia driver is now installed and it works. It didn't work with the Nouveau driver until when I booted from a live usb and then restarted from that session. I'm confused too.

Comment: OK! That's expected behaviour!  The nouveau drivers don't work yet on all hardware with all features... See the [Nouveau feature matrix](http://nouveau.freedesktop.org/wiki/FeatureMatrix/)  So you did the right thing from the start and probably cold booted in the mean time...  ;-)